# Python Paramiko, PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python-3.x

There is a daemon that goes to a remote server and fetches files from it. Then performs operations on them. Some files it picks up without any problems. But it gives an error on one of them. I can't figure out why. The file extensions are identical.
Error on a file that was previously uploaded to the save folder. There were no other files in the save folder, so it works correctly. How do I get around this error so that sftp_client will update the file if it is already in the directory?

```
        ....
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
try:
    ssh.connect(hostname=ip, username=user_name, password=passwd)
except Exception:
    logger.info("Server is not available, check that the data entered is correct")
    sys.exit()
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
path_serv = '/home/lacit/defect_storage/'  # Путь по которому производится поиск файлов
path_serv_file = sftp_client.listdir_attr(path=path_serv)  # Все файлы в по данному пути
    
if path_serv_file:
      for entry in path_serv_file:
          checking_number = os.path.splitext(entry.filename)[0]  # Split .png
          try:
              id_file_name = int(checking_number)  # Checking for number
              logger.info(f"Name of scan - {id_file_name}")
          except ValueError:
              logger.info(f"The scan name must have a numeric value \n Name of scan : {checking_number}")
              sys.exit()
          sftp_client.get(path_serv + entry.filename, '/home/ubuntu/media/' + entry.filename)
                #  Сохранение пути файла
          path_file_save = '/home/ubuntu/media/' + entry.filename
                #  Переменная обновления даты
          update_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    
          logger.info(f"Try to save or update data for leather - {id_file_name}")
          Defect.objects.update_or_create(id_leather=id_file_name,
                                                defaults={'update': update_date,
                                                          'result_auto': None,
                                                          'result_manual': None,
                                                          'path': path_file_save})
    
                logger.info("Try to call defection_start")

                ....
```

An error in the line `sftp_client.get(path_serv + entry.filename, '/home/ubuntu/media/' + entry.filename)`

Screenshot from the console
[image]

Comment: There is `permission denied` error on the log. it means your image is not belong to username that you use in the ssh connection

Comment: @Rizquuula Thank you. The point is that different computers can put the image in the folder where the service accesses. it is a shared folder.